# Count the number of lines in binary image

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

Consider I have the following binary image (each pixel is either 0 or 255). How to count the number of lines (they could be straight or a little curvy). For example, in the picture, there are six lines except for the circle. The goal is to compute the number of cracks and its total areas.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this a true case or just a hand sketch ? Real-life problems are usually harder.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, it is just a hand sketch. I edited the post and uploaded the real image. It's a piece of coal with some cracks inside. So I was wondering what are the ways to compute the number of cracks.

Comment: As I expected, the true case has nothing to do with the sketch. It is a complete mess. You first have to objectivate what a crack is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the kind of problem you can just look at a single image and expect someone to be able to tell you how to solve it.  It is likely that a solution will require considerable experimentation.  It is hard to know a priori what might work.

If you want to try classical computer vision techniques, you might start by using [image processing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_image_processing) operations, such as [morphological operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology), [thresholding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)), followed by [skeletonization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_skeleton) and some kind of post-processing.

If you truly had straight lines, you could use the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) to find lines.  However your edit makes clear that these are not straight lines.

Likely you will need to try something, see how well it works on many images, identify failure cases, hypothesize possible solutions, try multiple ideas to see if any of them help, and repeat.  Given the one image you have shown us, it is possible that this task might be quite challenging and it might take a lot of effort and knowledge of computer vision to make progress on it.

In practice, a more realistic solution might be to hire MTurk workers to hand-annotate the cracks for you, or to do it manually.

Comment: Taking something like edge detection and turning it into more semantic features like "contiguous lines" used to be referred to as *perceptual organisation*. I think it's fallen out of vogue a bit in the neural network era, but if you ask your favourite search engine about "perceptual organisation computer vision", you might have some luck.